# PFQuery not getting identificator

Tags: ios, parse-platform, pfquery

In the first PFQuery (passengers) I get several meanings, among which are sometimes far apart special identifier, which must transmit data in the second PFQuery (trip). Data from the first identifier must be passed in getObjectInBackgroundWithId: XXXX (class trip). How can I do this?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *gestureRight;
gestureRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeRight:)];
[[self view] addGestureRecognizer:gestureRight];

PFQuery *passenger = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"ClubWorld"];
[passenger getObjectInBackgroundWithId:@"zB96iIkoqo" block:^(PFObject *ClubWorld, NSError *error) {
    // Do somethi   ng with the returned PFObject in the gameScore variable.
NSLog(@"%@", ClubWorld);
    self.firstName.text = ClubWorld[@"firstName"];
    self.lastName.text = ClubWorld[@"lastName"];
    self.Mileage.text = ClubWorld[@"clubMiles"];
    self.withBAFrom.text = ClubWorld[@"withBAFrom"];
    self.withFCFrom.text = ClubWorld[@"withFCFrom"];
    self.fundsSpent.text = ClubWorld[@"fundsSpent"];
    self.lastTrip.text = ClubWorld[@"lastTrip"];
    self.previoustripObjectID = ClubWorld[@"lastTrip"];
}];

PFQuery *trip = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Trips"];
[trip getObjectInBackgroundWithId:self.previoustripObjectID block:^(PFObject *TripInformation, NSError *error) {
    // Do something with the returned PFObject in the gameScore variable.
NSLog(@"%@", TripInformation);
    self.fromCountry.text = TripInformation[@"fromCountry"];
    self.toCountry.text = TripInformation[@"toCountry"];
    self.departureAirport.text = TripInformation[@"departureAirport"];
    self.arrivalAirport.text = TripInformation[@"arrivalAirport"];
    self.earnedMiles.text = TripInformation[@"earnedMiles"];
    self.flightClass.text = TripInformation[@"flightClass"];
    self.departureTime.text = TripInformation[@"departureTime"];
    self.arrivalTime.text = TripInformation[@"arrivalTime"];
    self.flightCost.text = TripInformation[@"flightCost"];
}];

[super viewDidLoad];
```

}

Comment: What exactly is the error?

Comment: I need to transfer a response that comes from PFQuery * passenger in PFQuery * trip

Comment: NSLog(@"%@", ClubWorld); // brings me the answer from the server Parse.

[trip getObjectInBackgroundWithId:NEED_INSERT_OBJECT // And here I need to insert a value that I received with NSLog

I can not pass a value to pass that I received.

Comment: And your saying self.lastTrip.text isn't working as the objectID?

Comment: I tried to insert values _lastTrip, self.lastTrip.text and nothing. I can show you how to do the program works. Maybe an example will be more clear?

Comment: They are in the same ViewController. If we substitute in getObjectInBackgroundWithId:<value> ViewController then display the information.

Comment: So my question is, does self.lastTrip.text (the label) actually display the correct objectID?

Comment: UILabel shows that came ID and displays it on the screen. But I need to insert it into the trip getObjectInBackgroundWithId:

Comment: I did as you said, but still I have nothing appears.   See: http://s24.postimg.org/itmvmpcp1/image.png

Comment: Still do not come from a second data class. May need to download them consistently?

Comment: It's probably not working because your trying to put a value in the place of an ObjectID. lastTrip isn't an ObjectID

Comment: I now commit new code

Comment: It's also because in the second query lastTrip isn't in that class so it's not getting the objectID because it's in the ClubWorld class. Sorry I overlooked these things before. I'm working on my iPhone. You can't cross query classes like that

Comment: Sorry I don't need the project. As stated above. You can't reference another classes object id if your querying a different class. Post a picture of how your classes are set up in the parse backend

Comment: http://s17.postimg.org/4llkondsv/image.png

Comment: Yes.so basically  In the second query your trying to find an object id of a value, secondly, that value is in a different class. You can't cross query classes with parameters. In other words you can't query ClubWorld data in the Trip class. You have to find an object id of a row in the Trip class.  Your going to have to learn how to use pointers and relations

Comment: Could you help me do this? I first worked with Parse and I can not figure out how to do it.

Comment: https://parse.com/tutorials/one-to-many-relationships

Comment: Does not work, please check whether I put the pointer? 
    PFQuery *trip = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Trips"];
    [trip whereKey:@"lastTrip" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
    [trip getObjectInBackgroundWithId:@"lastTrip" block:^(PFObject *TripInformation, NSError *error) {

Comment: You didn't set any relationship. lastTrip isn't a relation to current user. And again, lastTrip has to be in the Trips class you can't cross query classes. Is lastTrips in the Trips class in your backend?

Comment: Did you make a column in your ClubWorld class that is a relation titled lastTrip that is related to _User?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PassengerViewController.h need write this code:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *previoustripObjectID;
```

In PassengerViewController.m need write this code:

-

```
 (void)viewDidLoad {
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *gestureRight;
    gestureRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeRight:)];
    [[self view] addGestureRecognizer:gestureRight];

    [self passengerRequest];
    [self previousTrip];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)passengerRequest {
    PFQuery *passenger = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"ClubWorld"];
    [passenger getObjectInBackgroundWithId:@"jnDrQthmQX" block:^(PFObject *ClubWorld, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", ClubWorld);
        self.profilePhoto = ClubWorld[@"passengerPhoto"];
        self.firstName.text = ClubWorld[@"firstName"];
        self.lastName.text = ClubWorld[@"lastName"];
        self.Mileage.text = ClubWorld[@"clubMiles"];
        self.withBAFrom.text = ClubWorld[@"withBAFrom"];
        self.withFCFrom.text = ClubWorld[@"withFCFrom"];
        self.fundsSpent.text = ClubWorld[@"fundsSpent"];
        self.previoustripObjectID = ClubWorld[@"lastTrip"];
    }];
}

- (void)previousTrip {
    PFQuery *trip = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Trips"];
    [trip getObjectInBackgroundWithId:self.previoustripObjectID block:^(PFObject *TripInformation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", TripInformation);
        self.fromCountry.text = TripInformation[@"fromCountry"];
        self.toCountry.text = TripInformation[@"toCountry"];
        self.departureAirport.text = TripInformation[@"departureAirport"];
        self.arrivalAirport.text = TripInformation[@"arrivalAirport"];
        self.earnedMiles.text = TripInformation[@"earnedMiles"];
        self.flightClass.text = TripInformation[@"flightClass"];
        self.departureTime.text = TripInformation[@"departureTime"];
        self.arrivalTime.text = TripInformation[@"arrivalTime"];
        self.flightCost.text = TripInformation[@"flightCost"];
    }];
}
```